# Error from import statement "expected "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>"

Tags: objective-c, import, compiler-errors

I am having some trouble integrating Appirater into my app.  I have properly added all of the necessary files, and have the right code (I think), but I am getting an error when trying to implement it into my AppDelegate.m file.  When I do `#import "Appirater.h"` I get the error:

> Expected "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>

Comment: Check for a bad character on your #import statement.  (Maybe delete and re-enter it.)

Comment: Weird... All I had to do is retype the quotes, and it now works! Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apparently the wrong quote characters, perhaps curly quotes `“Appirater.h”`, had been used to wrap the file name. Retyping them as "straight" quotes `"Appirater.h"` eliminated the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had `#import Firebase;`, instead of `#import <Firebase.h>`.