# How to mix and match Swift and Obj-C within a library project

Tags: xcode, swift

I've got an existing Obj-C project and want to start writing new code for it in Swift.

So I created a new Swift file that I added to the project (and Xcode created a bridging header for me). 
Now I want to access the class inside the Swift file within my Obj-C code. I've seen this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

and this:

[How to import Swift code to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c)

and this:

[Swift to Objective-C header not created in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062618/swift-to-objective-c-header-not-created-in-xcode-6)

And so have tried adding the following line to my Obj-C .m file as described in those references:

```
#import “NameOfMyProject-Swift.h”
```

But that gives an error of "Expected FILENAME or ".

The project type is a library, the product name doesn't have space or . characters and the Defines Module setting has been set to YES.

As one is supposed to be able to mix and match Swift and Obj-c in the same project whats wrong with my implementation of this?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627219/error-from-import-statement-expected-filename-or-filename as well.

Comment: Yes that was it. Cheers